# Proper way to get user by an attribute in mongoose nestjs

Tags: javascript, mongoose, nestjs

I have a user collection in the database and i want to retrive a user with specific username
I have written this method but this is returning all users

```
 findByUsername(username: string) {      
        return this.userModel.find({
            'username' : username})

    }
```

Why is this query not working
Controller

```
@Get('find/:username')
    getUserById(@Param("username") username : string) : any {
        console.log(username);
        return this.usersService.findByUsername(username);
    }
```

This is my user entity

import { Schema, SchemaFactory } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import { ApiProperty } from "@nestjs/swagger";

export type UserDocument = User & Document;

```
@Schema()
export class User {
    
    @ApiProperty()
    id: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    username: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    email : string

    @ApiProperty()
    password: string;
}

  export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```

This is the service

```
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { InjectModel } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import { Model } from "mongoose";
import { use } from "passport";
import {User,UserDocument} from '../users/entities/user.entity'

// This should be a real class/interface representing a user entity


@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
   
     constructor(
        @InjectModel(User.name) private readonly userModel : Model<User> )
        {}

    findById(userId: string) {
      
    }
    findByUsername(username: string) {      
        return this.userModel.find({"username": username}).exec();

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
findByUsername(username: string) {      
    return this.userModel.find({username: username}).exec();
}
```

or simplified version:

```
findByUsername(username: string) {      
    return this.userModel.find({username}).exec();
}
```

Briefly, the cause is the 'username' field typed with quotes and missing `.exec()` method at the end of the chain.

Also, schema should be prepared for Mongoose by decorating fields with the @Prop() decorator:

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Schema()
export class User {
    
    @ApiProperty()
    @Prop()
    id: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    @Prop()
    username: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    @Prop()
    email : string

    @ApiProperty()
    @Prop()
    password: string;
}

  export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```

Comment: This is the excalty code that i have written and asked why is not working you just wrote the same thing

Comment: Not exactly. Please notice how the filter is defined. You have put the username field in quotes like 'username' and it's not the same what I've done. Please try this code and the let me know what is the result.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: What am i missing ?

Comment: Can you then check your schema (using mongoexpress) if this field name is correct and there is no misspelling?

Comment: Do you want me to send to you the model  class?

Comment: I've just amended the response by adding the .exec() part at the and. Can you try it again?

Comment: I ll update the question now

Comment: Still the same sorry

Comment: check my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237398/discussion-between-mazooma-and-thymeleaf).

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to use .lean() instead of exec

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `findOne` method in Mongoose:

```js
findByUsername(username: string) {      
   return this.userModel.findOne({ username })
}
```